# LinQ Query from different tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is something like this possible?

```
var query = _context.Group
    .Where(g => g.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
    .Select(g => new GroupDTO {
        Name = g.GroupName,
        StartDate = g.StartDate,
        AvailableTeachers = _context.Teacher.Where(t => t.Available)
    });
```

Problem is, that the availableTeachers are not linked to the group in any way in the database - I would still store them into my DTO for later use - is this possible? I keep getting an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlFunctionExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.
```

**UPDATE**

This one works though and is so much better than what I tried:

```
var teachers = _context.Teacher.Where(t => t.Available).ToList();

var query = _context.Group
    .Where(g => g.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
    .Select(g => new GroupDTO {
        Name = g.GroupName,
        StartDate = g.StartDate,
        AvailableTeachers = teachers
    });
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You could first execute query `var availableTeachers = _context.Teacher.Where(t => t.Available).TOArray();` and then assign to for each DTO. Preferable teachers should have own DTO class.

Comment: I edited it to add the error message and also tried your approach - didnt work either

Comment: EF and all ORMs deal with *entities and relations* not tables and joins. The `Group` (bad name) entity should have a `Teachers` collection property containing `Teacher` entities. EF itself will generate the correct SQL to load group a group and its related teachers when you simply load the group. In EF Core 5+ you should be able to write `var groups=_context.Groups.Include(g=>g.Teachers.Where(t=>t.Available)).ToList();`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I know, but my example is a gross simplification, its an edge case where we cannot really have a connection between the 2 entities

Comment: In that case ask the *real* question. It's quite possible you *can* specify the relation, just not in the way you thought. Or the entities (not tables) are wrong. You can easily map entities to *views*. In fact, in reporting scenarios it's almost a necessity.

Comment: Full featured ORMs like NHibernate and Entity Framework are meant to map *entities* to tables and give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of databases and tables. If you find yourself writing code as if you were using a database, you're not just doing it wrong, you're fighting against the tool. It would be simpler in that case to just write the SQL query and use a micro-ORM like eg Dapper to map the results directly to objects

Answer (score 2):

```
// fetch all the list of teachers who are available stored in memory.
var teachers = _context.Teacher.Where(t => t.Available).ToList();

// to get the group record
var query = _context.Group
    .Where(g => g.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
    .Select(g => new GroupDTO {
        Name = g.GroupName,
        StartDate = g.StartDate,
        AvailableTeachers = teachers
    });
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws the same error

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? @Chi

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlFunctionExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.
@rohit

Comment: I have updated the above code. could you please check? @Chi

Comment: that one I cannot do, I cannot make a tolist for the groups because I still need to filter the query later. but thank you!

Comment: But it turns out it was a later modification that threw the error, your first version worked! so Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As teachers are not connected to groups in any way, you could optimize this by not including the request to teachers in the request for groups. As your statement is built now, you try to fetch the available teachers for each group again. If you have n groups, this means you will have n requests for teachers with the same results (if availability of the teachers does not change).

You can optimize this by splitting the requests, e.g.:

```
// Get the available teachers first (ToArray runs the query)
var teachers = _context.Teacher.Where(t => t.Available).ToArray(); 
// Get the groups
var query = _context.Group
    .Where(g => g.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
    .Select(g => new GroupDTO {
        Name = g.GroupName,
        StartDate = g.StartDate,
    })
    .ToArray()             // This runs the query against the db
    .Select(g => {
      AvailableTeachers = teachers;
      return g;
    })                     // This adds the teachers information after the db query
    .ToArray();
```

Above statement first reads the teachers from the database and stores them in a variable. After that, the groups are read from database. After the `ToArray`, the information is in memory and the list of available teachers is set.

Comment: Side note: I'd rather put `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToArray()` in the first place in order to have Linq to objects (`IEnumerable<T>`) and add teachers information